# DynomoDB write throttle issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We have write throttle really high consistently, when I am looking at the write capacity, it is not even consuming full capacity.

Please find the attached screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Are you spreading the Write requests over a large range of Partition Key values? If they are spread over a small range of values, you will not be able to benefit from the full capacity. Have a read of [The million dollar engineering problem](https://segment.com/blog/the-million-dollar-eng-problem/).

Answer (score 2):

This happens probably because of table workload not being evenly distributed across all partitions.

As per your screenshot, your table's write capacity is set to approx. 700 units. If the table has multiple partitions, say 10, then each individual 
partition can consume only 700/10 = 70 units per second.

Say, you need to write 100 records per second for one specific hash key (for simplicity let's suppose that 1 write consumes 1 WCU, which may not be the case if your record size exceeds 1Kb). Since each hash key belongs to a single partition, you will need to have 100 WCU per partition. But you only have 70. So in that specific case you will end up consuming only 70 WCU per table and having some of write requests throttled.

So, what is happening in your case: looks like your application tries to write into *some* of the table's partitions with speed that exceeds 
provisioned capacity available for an individual partition (that's why you get throttling), while *some other* partitions do not receive enough writes to consume all that capacity (that's why total table's capacity is not reached)

Also, I would suggest you reading this doc page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html

Answer (score 0):

The graph shows the 1 minute average. Try see the graph in CloudWatch console with maximum instead of average.